# Any alternatives or ways to make this script faster?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have this script which displays the terminal type being used. So for instance if you were running konsole it would display konsole. The script needs to go into another program that runs when a terminal is opened so it has to be very fast. Here's what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
SHELLTTY=$(exec ps -p "$$" -o tty=)
P=$$
while read P < <(exec ps -p "$P" -o ppid=) && [[ $P == +([[:digit:]]) ]]; do
    if read T < <(exec ps -p "$P" -o tty=) && [[ $T != "$SHELLTTY" ]]; then
        ps -p "$P" -o comm=
        break
    fi
done
```

When the script is saved into a file it takes this long for it to run.

```
[~]$ time ./termgrab
konsole

real    0m0.063s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.040s
```

The whole program itself takes .04 seconds so this slows it down considerably. Does anyone have any suggestions to make the script any faster or any alternative ways to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Still investing time into the same thing? You already chewed on this 5 days ago! And now you try to save some fractions of seconds?

Comment: Yeah, the script needs to load practicaly before the gui for the terminal even opens so having it load in 1/20'th of a second or below is somewhat crutial and unfortunately I don't really understand the script above as much as I should.

Comment: If you are talking about a race condition then put the script in a wrapper around the gui to guarantee that it has finished.

Comment: Recode that script in C using `/proc` if time matters so much. But I would not take that pain. Or simply use the `TERM` environment variable (and perhaps the `tty` and `stty` commands)

Comment: BTW, I am not even sure that your goal has any sense. All terminal emulators should behave equivalently, and I don't understand why you want to distinguish them. Also, there are many of them, and you might not cover all the cases. Then `TERM` variable should be enough (and `termcap` defines quite well what it means)